# Metric Space Question Structure Problem

Tags: metric-spaces

Que.)   $\{x ∈ :( \;, y)≤ r\}$ defined in metric space is known as ___________ ball.

Hey guys, i had given an exam recently and this was the question i have to attempt.... I know this question answer, but I want to know only that "is this question format correct or not ?" means in this question there is blank space on left side of coma of '$y$' . Is this standard representation for metric space or is this a wrong format?

Please help me out if this is wrongly formatted then it can save my 1 mark in exam.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. We usually recommend formatting with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). To answer your question, I suppose people have their own notation but I have never seen that.

Comment: For one thing, inside the set bracket is a membership symbol just sitting there, not between any two things like usual in $x \in A$ [I mean it has a $\in$ symbol with nothing immediately to its right.]

Comment: @coffeemath thanks for answering.....you want to say question format is not correct. Am i right?

Comment: It's not standard notation  in set theory nor metric-space theory and I dk what it means but on a test I would guess "closed ball".

Comment: Other things I would be missing: a) a definition what $y$ might be (is it a member of the metric space? b) the inequality seems to be meaningless. Maybe if $d$ is the metric then this inequality is intended to express $d(x,y) \leq r$ but a candidate should not be judged on his ability to autocomplete the question.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks for solving my doubt, i understood what you want to say, and yes its answer is "Closed Ball".

Comment: @Maksim Thanks for explaining all things clearly, you solved my doubt.